# Initialising a System.Decimal v Initialisting a decimal data type

Tags: c#

I am use to using the decimal data type like this:

```
decimal Cost = 30M;
```

This initialises the decimal with £30 (£ is in the context of my application).  I am planning to use a type alias for Decimal in my application like this:

```
using Cost = System.Decimal
```

I believe I have to use the object rather than the primitive type when using a type alias.  Please let me know if that is not correct?

Also I have noticed that I cannot do this:

```
Decimal cost = new Decimal(30M);
```

I have to do this instead:

```
Decimal cost = new Decimal(30);
```

Is the initialisation code above suitable for a currency?

Comment: `new Decimal`? Why would you want to use a `Decimal` constructor? Also, why alias a built-in type?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm guessing to make explicit in code that the type is used as a monetary value.

Answer (score 1):

> This initialises the decimal with £30 (£ is in the context of my application). I am planning to use a type alias for Decimal in my application like this: `using Cost = System.Decimal`

Ok, thats a valid option.

> I believe I have to use the object rather than the primitive type when using a type alias. Please let me know if that is not correct?

I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you are using a type alias, the whole idea is to use it:

```
var cost = new Cost(10);
```

Rememnber, a type alias is a type alias; wherever you can `System.Decimal`, `Cost` is valid too.

> Also I have noticed that I cannot do this: `Decimal cost = new Decimal(30M);`

Yup, and you can't do `Cost cost = new Cost(30M);` either, because `decimal` doesn't define such constructor overload. The reason being, if you already have a `Decimal` / `Cost` in hand why in the world would you want to new it up again? `Cost cost = 30M;` would do just fine.

Also notice that `Cost cost = 30;` is just fine too, the compiler will perform the implicit conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I also have a DateTime.  Can I initialise this without the new operator?

Comment: @w0051977 No, C# does not support date constant literals (`var d = #01/10/18` or similar), you need the new operator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you need to use the fully qualified type name to use an alias. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#remarks):

   > Create a using alias to make it easier to qualify an identifier to a namespace or type. The right side of a using alias directive **must always be a fully-qualified type** regardless of the using directives that come before it.

   It's worth noting that using a type alias is very uncommon, particularly when using a built in value type like `decimal`. I would not recommend that you do that.
2. You can't do `new Decimal(30M)` because the type doesn't have a constructor that takes a decimal, after all it would be pointless because you can simply do this (where the `M` qualifier is optional):

   ```
   Decimal cost = 30M;
   ```

Comment: The `M` qualifier is **NOT** optional. Without it, [the number is treated as a double and generates a compiler error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal).

Comment: @DavidG: The following `decimal dd = 30.54;` produces compiler error CS0664 `Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'decimal'; use an 'M' suffix to create a literal of this type.`

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Indeed, but this question doesn't contain that number, it contains an integer.